# WCF Data Services: call service operation

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

I have an instance WCF Data Services with the service operation.

```
[WebGet]
    public IQueryable<long> TestMethod() {
        long[] instanceNumberArray = new long[] { 1 };
        return instanceNumberArray.AsQueryable();
    }
```

I try call it in this way:

```
Uri EndPointAddressUri = new Uri(@"http://localhost:9227/ReviewServiceWDS.svc/");
DataServiceContext context = new DataServiceContext(EndPointAddressUri);
DataServiceQuery<long> query = context.CreateQuery<long>("TestMethod");
var result = query.Execute();
var value = result.FirstOrDefault();
```

On the last row I catch the Exception:

Error processing response stream. The XML element contains mixed content.

In the same time Internet Explorer returns:

`<TestMethod> 
        <element p2:type="Edm.Int64">1</element>
 </TestMethod>`

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

DataServiceContext.CreateQuery only takes EntitySetName as parameter. You need to use DataServiceContext.Execute to call service operations.

Comment: Also, which version of WCF Data services (Microsoft.Data.Services.Client) are you using? Make sure you are using the latest package (5.4RTM) bits. You can download it from Nuget.org.

Comment: Thank you very much, Cynthia!
I must read MSDN more curefully.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230677.aspx

Thank you, Pratik.
I use version 5.3. I didn't know about this release.